# IntelliJ Idea 16 CE gradle issues

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

In my gradle file I am trying to use the following to solve another issue. This is my gradle file:

```
group 'com.winapp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/java/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.intellij:forms_rt:6.0.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

task copyDependenciesToTarget(type: Copy) {
    println 'Copying dependencies to target...'

    configurations.compile.collect().each { compileDependency ->
        copy {
            with from (compileDependency.getPath()) {
                include '*'
            }
            into 'target/libs/libs'
        }
    }
}

build.dependsOn(copyDependenciesToTarget)


jar {
    manifest.attributes(
            "Main-Class": "Main",
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { 'libs/' +     it.getName()}.join(' ')
    )
}
```

The problem are is this:

```
configurations.compile.collect().each { compileDependency ->
        copy {
            with from (compileDependency.getPath()) {
                include '*'
            }
            into 'target/libs/libs'
        }
    }
```

When I run the application I get this Exception:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecWrapper_Decorated cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecInternal
```

Main problem is, I have no idea how to fix this error, I simply want my project to create a JAR file that works with JDBC, using this gradle code seems to be a solution for that issue, but now I have run into another problem, yet again.

Please let me know if you require any additional information and thank you in advance. Literally, I cant even. This problem.

**EDIT**

As stated in the comments. My project runs fine when I run it through the IDE. There is an issue when I create a JAR file using gradle. The bare gradle file that IntelliJ created when I started the gradle project follows (Added the jar config so my Main class would be picked up):

```
group 'com.winapp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/java/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.intellij:forms_rt:6.0.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

jar {
    manifest.attributes(
            "Main-Class": "Main",
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { 'libs/' + it.getName()}.join(' ')
     )
}
```

When I execute my app from terminal after the JAR has been created (keeping in mind there are no issues when hitting run in the IDE) with java -jar myAppName.jar:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

**NOTE:** Usually I get a full stack running a java app, but in this case the above is the only output.

I am using this JAR for my sqlite needs:

```
sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1
```

As a test I commented out the Sqlite usage in my application and the JAR file worked fine. My GUI was displayed and everything went as expected (all things considered). The JAR stops working when I add the sqlite JAR file usage (code). Added it the same as my other libs (like retrofit), so this seems to be quite a strange issue.

Please let me know if I have explained the issue correctly?

Comment: It looks like you should just use the application plugin, which does all that for you (and more). Note that your question has absolutely nothing to do with IntelliJ.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi, thats just the thing. I am and its not working. I keep getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC if I just run with the gradle plugin. So I'm trying to get this working to solve that problem.

Comment: So, do you have the sqlite driver in your compile or runtime dependencies? Why the hell do you store jars under src/main/java, which is the directory used for source files?

Comment: @JBNizet I have it in my compile dependencies yes. And quite honestly, this is my first pure Java project. I just want to get the beast running correctly with what I need (JDBC being crucial). I will make it pretty at a later stage.

Comment: Post the following information: your updated gradle file using the application plugin, the contents of the lib folder containing the jar files, the content of the zip file generated by the application plugin, how you start the application, the exact and complete stack trace of your exception.

Comment: @JBNizet Will do. Just need to add. The project runs without a problem when I run it through the IDE. No issues with the JDBC driver so obviously it is added correctly. The problem is that when I create a JAR file using gradle I get the sqlite error. Sorry for the misleading comment. When I went through it again I realized I left out the JAR bit.

Comment: @JBNizet Hey, so I updated my question and added additional information with some more context, can you please have a look?

Comment: You're still not using the application plugin, which would do everything right. And you haven't posted the command line used to start your app. In fact, you haven't posted any of the things I asked.

Comment: @JBNizet java -jar JavaWinApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar . It should be obvious at this point, this is my first time doing this type of thing. How would I go about using the application plugin?

Comment: @JBNizet I added this in my gradle.build: 
apply plugin: 'application'. Got an additional task that says run, but thats pretty much it

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the help. I was unaware that the plugin was literally just apply plugin: 'application'. Thought it was some IDE settings etc. I will be fine from here :). Good docs is usually always the answer